Black iron gas pipe penetrating cinder block wall above grade - sleeving requirements
I'm upgrading my propane lines inside the house and plan on having a 1" black iron pipe stub out from the basement cinder block wall (2ft above grade). I'm having a hard time finding a conclusive answer on the correct way to do this. Does this require a sleeve? If so, will regular 1.5" PVC pipe work? If no sleeve is required, does pipe wrap serve as a sufficient barrier or is any barrier between BIP and cinder block / concrete needed at all? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Your local building department will have the right answer for your locality.

@crip659 Is there a general accepted best practice for this type situation?
